# What does the .NET Regex "\19abc" match?

Tags: .net, regex, octal, backreference

I am studying .NET Regular Expression.
As known there is an ambiguity between octal escape codes (such as \16) and \number backreferences.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx

My question is:
**What does regular expressions like `\19` or `\288` match when the group with that number is not defined in the regex pattern?**

Neither it is a valid group number nor it is a valid octal code.
But it is a valid regular expression (even `\14848486` is valid) - the Regex constructor does not throw an ArgumentException but I could not find any input string that match such an escape sequence.

I am just curious how to interpret just an expression.

Comment: `\14848486` matches an octal 14, and then a sequence of `848486`

Comment: Sorry. I meant `\18848486` (when the second number is 8 or 9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambiguity arises when there are several possibilities to parse a pattern. Say, in `(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)\10` pattern with 10  capturing groups we can speak of an ambiguity since `1` and `10` can both refer to the existing group, but .NET regex engine resolves this ambiguity to the biggest possible value, and this regex [won't match `12345678901`, but will match `12345678900`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%5C10&i=12345678900%0D%0A12345678901). To get rid of the ambiguity, you need to use `\k<ID>` backreferences. [`(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)\k<1>0`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%28.%29%5Ck%3C1%3E0&i=123456789000%0D%0A123456789010) would match `123456789010`, but not `123456789000`.

The `\14848486` pattern matches an octal 14 character, and then a sequence of `848486` as there is no ambiguity here.

The `\18848486` pattern will match an octal 1 char, and then a sequence of `8848486` chars. See [this C# demo](http://ideone.com/XHKcRK):

```
var s = Regex.Match("\u00018848486", @"\18848486");
if (s.Success) Console.WriteLine(s.Value); // => 8848486
```

I also suggest using Ultrapico Expresso (no affiliation)  to debug .NET regexps, see the screenshot:

[image]

As for `\19` and `\288`:

[image]

Besides, when you use a backreference to the group that is missing, as in `\k<1>8848486`, you [will get a *`System.ArgumentException: parsing '\k<1>8848486' - Reference to undefined group number N`* exception](http://ideone.com/AlVDOX). When you have `8` or `9` after `\`, as in `\8848486`, you will get [*`System.ArgumentException: parsing '\8848486' - Unrecognized escape sequence N`* exception](http://ideone.com/VZSr9c).

Comment: "The \18848486 pattern will match an octal 1 char, and then a sequence of 8848486 chars."
Are you sure? Regarding the MSDN octal representation need two or tree digits and not just one.
But thanks. however, I will try it out.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The .NET regex engine allows this shorter octal char notations. There are 2 cases when there is `8` or `9` after the backslash, then there is a parsing exception thrown.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just checked it into the Visual Studio C# interactive window - and the results are the same:

    > System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch( ((char)1).ToString() + "9", @"^\01[9]");   //
    true
    > System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch( ((char)1).ToString() + "9", @"^\19");   //
    true

Comment: Can you confirm my answer please? Is may summary right?

Answer (score 0):

Wiktor Stribiżew is right.

Here is my summary for the **default (Canonical)** behavior of the .NET Regex Engine

- The expressions `\1` through `\9` (with no further following digit) are always interpreted as backreferences, and not as octal codes. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx)
- Using the `\1` through `\9` will lead to an ArgumentException if in the regex pattern no capturing group of this specified number is defined. (`parsing '\8' - Reference to undefined group number`)
- If it is an multidigit expression, the Regex engine first tries to match the sequence of decimal digits (after the `\`) as backreference to that numbered group (capturing group).
- If no capturing group with that number in the regex pattern is defined, then the engine tries to interpret the sequence of digits as an octal code:
- If there are 3 or more octal digits (0...7) in sequence then the engine matches the character of the code with the first 3 digits. Any other following digit will be matches as literal.

  - Example: `\040` → matches `octal 040`
  - Example: `\0040` → matches `octal 004`, then `0`
  - Example: `\134` → matches `octal 134`
  - Example: `\134567` → matches `octal 134`, then `5`, then `6`, then `7`
- Else, if there are 2 octal digits (0...7) then the engine matches the 
  character of the code with this 2 digits. Any other following digit will be matches as literal.

  - Example: `\049` → matches `octal 04`, then `9`
  - Example: `\13` → matches `octal 13`
  - Example: `\138567` → matches `octal 13`, then `8`, then `5`, then `6`, then `7`
- Else, if there is only 1 octal digit (0...7) then the engine matches the character of the code with this 1 digit. Any other following digit will be matches as literal.

  - Example: `\0` → matches `octal 0`
  - Example: `\08` → matches `octal 0`, then `8`
  - Example: `\7` → matches `octal 7`
  - Example: `\19456` → matches `octal 1`, then `9`, then `4`, then `5`, then `6`
- Else, if there are zero octal digits after the backslash, then the engine will throw the ArgumentException.

  - Example: `\81` → throws `ArgumentException`: `parsing '\81' - Unrecognized escape sequence \8`
  - Example: `\975` → throws `ArgumentException`: `parsing '\975' - Unrecognized escape sequence \9`

But **NOTE**:
The behavior is different if you use the RegexOption `ECMAScript`.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#ECMAScript